# What do you call someone who tells jokes that nobody laughs at

Tags: phrase-request

There is this similar question [When you tell a joke and nobody laughs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117202/when-you-tell-a-joke-and-nobody-laughs) about how you feel if you be in such a situation, but I would like to know the words on the other side:

- What do you call such a joke?
- What do you call the person who said such a joke?
- How do you describe your feeling of hearing such a joke?
- What may you say to that person?

In Persian, I can think of *a tasteless joke*, *a tasteless person*, *a cool or cold or light or happy person!*, *I felt cold*, *I felt freezed*, ....you may say him "laugh on water!", especially if the joke was targeted to tease you...

*Then don't get excited if a Persian said you "you are very cool"*,... hahaha was it cool? hahaha ...

Comment: The person telling the jokes can be called a "poor would-be comedian" or comedienne. Or just call the jokes *dad jokes*, but not because they are in bad taste, but because they are ***corny***, and make you *groan* audibly.

Comment: The only one I could find for a person who can't help but make bad jokes, or ["dad jokes"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Dad+Joke) as Mari-Lou has noted, is ["a punster"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=punster). The rest of your request was answered  [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117202/when-you-tell-a-joke-and-nobody-laughs)

Comment: *Go laugh on water*?  Does that mean "Go drown yourself?" Or is it closer to "Get outta here"?

Comment: @tromano "laugh" in this phrase is subjunctive. Maybe "I wish you laugh on the water", I myself added "go" and it seems I mistook. However we also say "go die", "go drown yourself", "go hang yourself", etc., but as I searched "On the water" refers to the water or the board used to wash a dead person (ablution in Muslims tradition). It is said by you when someone is laughing by teasing you or saying unfunny jokes and means I hope you laugh as you are dead. I myself didn't know its exact meaning until today.  People may say many things while they don't know its meaning but its usage.

Answer (score 3):

The joke would be called something like a 'lead balloon'

There isn't really a specific word for a person who told the joke. Maybe just that they have a bad sense of humor. Humorless might work, although that might not be a good word if they at least have some sense of humor, they *are* telling a joke after all, tasteless works quite well, but this is quite subjective, a tasteless joke is always a bad joke but a bad joke is not always a tasteless joke. Tasteless is generally applied to jokes that are considered offensive (and unfunny by the person listening). Bad is generally applied to any joke that is not funny.

The feeling, I guess would be disappointment if you were expecting a funny joke or exasperation, annoyance. It really depends on the person and the context of the situation.

A reaction, again, would depend on the person and the context, based on the feeling.

You might say a range of things, again, this really depends on the emotions that the joke evokes(is that the right word?) out of the person, there isn't really a standard response to any joke, although particular types of jokes may have standard responses.

Answer (score 3):

[Witling](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/witling) - someone thinks they're funny but they're not.

Comment: A number of dictionaries have marked that as "archaic", including [Lexico/Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/definition/witling) and [Google Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=witling&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwitling%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwitling%3B%2Cc0) seems to support that